# Collect every field of matching XML tags into a list in R

Tags: r, xml

I have an XML file of the following format

```
<Level1>
  <Level2>Data0</Level2>
</Level1>
<Level1>
  <Level2>Data1</Level2>
</Level1>
...
```

I want to get all the values of Level2 (Data0,Data1,etc...) into a list that will be a single field in a data frame. For now I have the following format for adding a cell to my data frame when there is only one thing that goes in the cell.

```
dat <- read_xml("link_to_my_xml_file")
VarName <- xml_text(xml_find_all(dat, "path/to/tag"))
```

So basically I want VarName to hold a list (Data0,Data1,etc...). How do I do that?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: `paste(VarName, collapse=",")`

Comment: I'm still ending up with multiple rows looking exactly the same except for the VarName field, where in the first row I see Data0, the second Data1, etc... Where would I put the paste call such that I avoid that?

Comment: Does this help?  Check `data.frame(a=1, b=1:3)` and `data.frame(a=1, b=paste(1:3, collapse=","))`?

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thank you so much!